# Qt inheritance and instantiation problems

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I have recently picked up an application I was working on some time ago.

Not soon after I already stumbled across a problem with inheritance.

I have a base class called ModelBase which has a pure virtual method, making it an abstract class. The class looks like followed:

```
#ifndef MODELBASE_H
#define MODELBASE_H

#include <QMetaType>
#include <QString>

class ModelBase
{
public:
    ModelBase();
    virtual ~ModelBase();

    long getId() const;
    void setId(const long id);

    virtual QString toString() const = 0;
private:
    long m_id;

};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ModelBase)

#endif // MODELBASE_H
```

The fact that it is declared as a METATYPE is probably something to keep in mind for reading the rest of the code.

I derived several classes from this base class. For this example I will use the two that gives me most problems.

```
#ifndef PLATFORM_H
#define PLATFORM_H

#include <QDate>

#include "modelbase.h"
#include "game.h"

class Platform : ModelBase
{
public:
    Platform();
    ~Platform();

    QString toString() const;

    QString getName();
    QDate getPublishDate();

    void setName(QString name);
    void setPublishDate(QDate publishDate);
private:
    QString m_name;
    QDate m_publishDate;
    QList<Game*> m_games;
};

#endif // PLATFORM_H
```

As you can see, the header also includes the virtual method from the parent class ModelBase.

Last but not least; the problem class:

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <QDate>

#include "modelbase.h"

class Platform;
class Publisher;
class Genre;

class Game : ModelBase
{
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();

    QString getTitle();
    Publisher* getPublisher();
    Genre* getGenre();
    Platform* getPlatform();
    QDate getPublishDate();
    QString getLentTo();

    void setTitle(QString title);
    void setPublisher(Publisher &publisher);
    void setGenre(Genre &genre);
    void setPlatform(Platform &platform);
    void setPublishDate(QDate date);
    void setLentTo(QString lentTo);

    QString toString() const;
private:
    QString m_title;
    Publisher *m_publisher;
    Genre *m_genre;
    Platform *m_platform;
    QDate m_publishDate;
    QString m_lentTo;
};

#endif // GAME_H
```

Now that the code is in place...

The first problem comes with circular dependency.

A platform has many games, a game has one platform.

I solved that by forward declaring platform in games.h and including games.h in platforms.h

Now that that is out of the way, I compiled my program and get the following complaints which i really don't understand.

```
xxxxx\mingw47_32\include\QtCore\qmetatype.h:382: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'ModelBase'
```

Ok fair enough.. But I am never really directly defining ModelBase in the classes. Only deriving from it.

Another error i get in the same log is:

```
xxxx\mingw47_32\include\QtCore\qmetatype.h:-1: In instantiation of 'static void* QtMetaTypePrivate::QMetaTypeFunctionHelper<T, Accepted>::Create(const void*) [with T = ModelBase; bool Accepted = true]':
```

I truly have no idea what is going on here.

I tried not using pointers at all in games.h but then i get different kind of compiler errors which i don't understand either;

```
xxxx\game.h:38: error: field 'm_platform' has incomplete type
```

I have tried using both #include and forward declarations but they all give they share of problems. Also note that if in the games.h file i replace the forward class declarations with includes(except platform.h, that would bring back the circular dependency issue) all the issues of has incomplete type dissapear (except m_platform because as far as i know, i have no choice but to forward declare it)

I assume I lack knowledge of how this inheritance is supposed to work here.

The reason I defined ModelBase as metatype is because I want ModelBase and its children to be wrapped/unwrapped in/from a QVariant

Comment: interesting. And [their docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/custom-types.html) don't say whether the class can be abstract

Comment: I couldn't find anything about it atleast. :P

Comment: Are you aware of the fact you are using private inheritance? Try using public inheritance instead.

Comment: @Jonny Dee I am not aware of that im using private inheritance. could you please point out what line indicates so?

Comment: @JoeyRoosing: You write "class Game : ModelBase". This is implicitly private inheritance. You need to write "class Game : public ModelBase" instead.

BTW, as Jan Kundrát already mentioned. You might want to define the metatype of the *pointer* to the abstract class, because QVariant cannot deal with abstract class types.

Comment: The Standard states: `In the absence of an access-specifier for a base class, **public** is assumed when the derived class is defined **with
the class-key struct** and **private** is assumed when the class is defined **with the class-key class**.`

Comment: @JonnyDee Ah, I got it. Thanks Daniel and Jonny. That makes alot of sense, I will fix this in my code. Still have a lot to learn it seems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last error occurs since you cannot have an object of an incomplete type in your class. The Compiler will not know how much space is to be allocated for this object so the memory layout of your class will be somehow undefined. A "pointer to incomplete" in contrast is possible.

I am not into Qt but it looks like your Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() results in a constructor call. Per definition an abstract class is not constructible.

`QMetaTypeFunctionHelper::Create` :

```
static void *Create(const void *t)
{
  if (t)
    return new T(*static_cast<const T*>(t));
  return new T();
}
```

The documentation [QMetaType Class Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) says :

> **Q_DECLARE_METATYPE ( Type )** This macro makes the type Type known to QMetaType as long as it provides a public default constructor, a public copy constructor and a public destructor. It is needed to use the type Type as a custom type in QVariant.

As i mentioned: abstract classes cannot be constructed.

See [[Qt-interest] Q_DECLARE_METATYPE and abstract classes](http://lists.qt.nokia.com/public/qt-interest/2011-August/035286.html) :

> On Monday, 8 de August de 2011 12:36:16 Schimkowitsch Robert wrote:
>
> > > How do I declare a metatype of an abstract base class? I have seen
> > >       nothing in the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE-docs that would forbid it.
>
> You don't. Metatypes require being default-constructible, publicly 
>   destructible, copyable and assignable.
>
> Abstract types cannot be constructed at all. By definition of abstract
>   as well,  you don't want to copy them, as doing that would shear the
>   specialised object  you had.
>
> More than likely, you want to register the metatype of the *pointer*
>   to the  abstract class.

Comment: This is an excellent answer and Daniel was also faster than I was.

Comment: Daniel Weber thanks alot for your answer, I got rid of most compile time errors and gained some new insights. thanks alot.

Answer (score 5):

The `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` on abstract class is indeed a problem. This does not "define a class a metatype", it makes that class available to the Qt's MOC for purposes like passing it around in signal/slot parameters, making it available in `QVariant` etc. However, you cannot do that on a class which is abstract -- it makes no sense. Are you sure you did not mean:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ModelBase*)
```

About the rest of the warnings -- when a compiler notices an error, most of them try to find other issues going forward in your source. Sometimes it works well, sometimes it just gives you spurious warnings. Fix the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` error and then work on the rest.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I have one problem that is still unclear to me though. I figured that if I make ModelBase a METATYPe all children will automatically also be a METATYPE. Hence why I wrote it in the ModelBase. I assume this is mostly due to lack of knowledge on my side?

Answer (score 1):

`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` is used when you want objects of a specific class to be used in QVariant (Qt advanced union) or to use these objects in signal and slot connections.

So it make no sense to use it for a object of a virtual class, because you are able to construct an object of a virtual class to begin with. First of all `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ModelBase*)` will not work because the parameter need to be a type (the parsing is really basic). Second it is not necessary because you can use any pointers in Qt without declaring it to the system.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I did notice that Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ModelBase*) get rids of the compiler errors asscociated with it, but it will take some time to see how it handles itself in runtime.

Comment: It is not just about compiler errors. It is about what you are trying to achieve. `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ModelBase*)` is a ***useless*** statement.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve was having each child class automatically be a METATYPE by enheriting from ModelBase. Safe to assume this is a false thought?

Comment: yes, it is a false thought. You have to declare metatype for each concrete class.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. As I continues working on the code, that was exactly what I experienced.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered a similar problem, while writing some code where I later on want to find the type of the stored pointer within a QVariant.

By Using `QVariant::canConvert<ModelBase*>` it is possible to determine the type of the pointer later on, hence it might be usefull to declare a typed pointer instead of using the default `void*`.